# Teams Document Tab Content URL Access Issue for External Users

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-teams

We are currently developing a Power Automate to integrate file tabs into Teams channels. According to the latest information from Microsoft, the website tab in Teams is slated for deprecation. Consequently, we explored using the Document tab as a viable alternative.

However, when attempting to add the Document tab, we encountered an issue. A content URL is required, and unfortunately, guest users in the Teams environment are unable to access the document when we add the Document tab using a content URL. Our objective is to ensure that the Document tab is accessible to all members, regardless of whether they are guests or regular members. We aim for universal permission access.

Has anyone else ever faced this issue?

Comment: Please take at this msft documentation regarding this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/files/guests-cannot-access-files
And: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/guest-users-cannot-access-the-files-tab-on-teams/f5cce699-94df-40fe-be7c-132e9ecb5e72